# Using redshift to adjust the brightness

Tags: xrandr

I adjust the brightness of my screen with `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness 0.75`, because the range of my physical backlight is not enough. Now I want to use [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/). So what happened is, if `redshift` is running I can't override the brightness via `xrandr`.

I tried to change the redshift.conf file, which is loaded at the program start, during the program is running but it has no effect. The parameter for brightness isn't read again after the file changed. So my question is how can I change the brightness parameter in redshift during the program is running? Do I have to restart redshift?

Comment: Looking at this area myself today and am wondering how this turned out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also looking for this and just found and used the -g argument:

```
redshift -O 3000 -g 0.5
```

Font:
https://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/02/redshift-change-screen-color-temp-brightness-based-time-day/

Answer (score 1):

From `redshift -h`:

```
...    
-b DAY:NIGHT Screen brightness to apply (between 0.1 and 1.0)
...
```

So, for example, you can try the following:

```
redshift -O 6000 -b 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

use "redshift -x" before applying any new settings